# Problemas de impresión en una red local

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, devexpress, impresora

Actualmente utilizo XtraReport para generar un reporte vía web (asp.net mvc 5 y c#),
pero se requiere ejecutar la impresión de reporte sin la necesidad de vista previa, he realizado el reporte con éxito y utilizo la función "ReportPrintTool" para mandar imprimir automatica, pero tengo problemas

Al ejecutar el proyecto local con iisExpress, manda con éxito la impresión, pero al publicar en un servidor local, no detecta la impresora, hice una prueba de mandar a imprimir la ip donde se esta ejecutando el sistema y resulta que es el servidor, asi la mejor manera es enviar la orden a una pc que comparte la impresora en la red local de la siguiente manera

```
 CapaReportes.Ticket report = new CapaReportes.Ticket(_Ticket);
  //parametros del reporte (sin advertencia de margenes y sin ventana de selección de impresora)
report.ShowPrintMarginsWarning = false;
report.ShowPrintStatusDialog = false;


//imprimir reporte
DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.ReportPrintTool rpt = new DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.ReportPrintTool(report);
rpt.Print("\\\\192.168.1.95\\HP LaserJet Professional P1102w");
```

pero el mensaje de error es el siguiente

> La configuración para obtener acceso a la impresora '\192.168.1.95\HP LaserJet Professional P1102w' no es válida.

**¿que me sugieren para resolver este problema?**
(gracias por su tiempo)

Comment: que mejor generes un PDF y que el usuario decida dónde lo va a imprimir. :D

Comment: gracias por comentar fredyfx, el detalle es que no se requiere una vista previa, ademas el reportito es para acceso público, por lo que no debe de estar visible a los cliente, solo que un boton que lo genere y mande a imprimir

Comment: ¿De verdad es un requisito mandar a imprimir sin necesidad de ver una vista previa?

Comment: asi es, es para uso de un kiosko y no se requiere una vista previa

Comment: entendido, esto podría funcionar: dale permisos a la impresora el acceso al usuario del IIS. En lugar de la IP, coloca el nombre de la computadora o en todo caso, añade esa impresora al servidor de impresión (como servicio del Windows Server)